# How to make keyboard uppercase?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textfield

I need the keyboard to be with CapsLock on (please don't answer how to make text in textField uppercased):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `.autocapitalizationType` for your `textField` in `viewDidLoad` or somewhere else during setup of the view like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
}
```

Now when your `textField` becomes active, your keyboard will be on caps.

[Here are](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextautocapitalizationtype) all the possible options for autocapitalizationType.

Answer (score 0):

The `.autocapitalization` attribute of `TextField` in SwiftUI is now marked for future deprecation, with a note saying to use                         `.textInputAutocapitalization(TextInputAutocapitalization?)` instead. Use it as follows

```
TextField("placeholder text", text: $textVariable)
    .textInputAutocapitalization(.characters)
```

The possible values for `TextInputAutocapitalization` are `.characters`, `.words`, `.never`, or the default value of `.sentences`. Note that if the user has Auto-Capitalizaiton turned off in `Settings>General>Keyboard>Auto-Capitalizaiton`, then `.textInputAutocapitalization` will have no effect.

Reference Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/textinputautocapitalization(_:)).